# ESLEIF not working as it pulling through wrong modules

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm having a problem with this if condition logic it keeps showing the second condition.

Can anyone confirm what am doing wrong?

```
%%[

IF (@journeytype == "00005201" AND @optstatus == "TRUE") THEN
    SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre")
    SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Destination GuidesPre")
    SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Nectar PointsPre")
    SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Our Free Travel AppPre")
ELSEIF (@journeytype == "00005201" AND @optstatus == "FALSE") THEN
    SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre")
    SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\At the stationPre")
    SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Smoother ConnectionsPre")
    SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Head OnlinePre")
ENDIF

]%%
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The logic appears right, although I would recommend 2 things.

1 - Use a nested If/Else

```
If @journeytype == "00005201" Then
    If @optstatus == "true" Then
        SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre") 
        SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Destination GuidesPre") 
        SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Nectar PointsPre") 
        SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Our Free Travel AppPre")
    Else
        SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre") 
        SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\At the stationPre") 
        SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Smoother ConnectionsPre") 
        SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Head OnlinePre")
    EndIf
Else EndIf
```

2 - Create a default content area. That is, for ContentAreaByName ,use it's ability to call in a default content area. This will help ensure that that the error is not inside the content area (oppose to with the macro logic).

Answer (score 0):

I would output your `@journeytype` and `@optstatus` variables and validate their values coming into the conditional.

```
%%[
outputLine(concat("@journeytype:  ",@journeytype,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat("@optstatus:  ",@optstatus,"<br>"))
IF (@journeytype == "00005201" AND @optstatus == "TRUE") THEN
    SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre")
    SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Destination GuidesPre")
    SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Nectar PointsPre")
    SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Our Free Travel AppPre")
ELSEIF (@journeytype == "00005201" AND @optstatus == "FALSE") THEN
    SET @contentblock1 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Travel UpdatesPre")
    SET @contentblock2 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\At the stationPre")
    SET @contentblock3 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Smoother ConnectionsPre")
    SET @contentblock4 = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Triggers\pre-post departures\Head OnlinePre")
ENDIF
]%%
```

You can strip leading zeroes with the [RegExMatch()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#RegExMatch) function if you need to. Here's an example from [my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/regex-in-ampscript/):

```
%%[
var @s, @o, @p, @m

outputLine(concat("<h4>Strip leading zeroes from a string</h4>"))
set @s = "0000012345"
set @p = "^0*(\d+)$"
set @o = RegExMatch(@s, @p, 1)
outputLine(concat("input:  ",@s,"<br>"))
outputLine(concat('pattern: "',@p,'"<br>'))
outputLine(concat("output: ",@o,"<br>"))

]%%
```